# Extending should.js with a custom function

Tags: javascript, node.js, should.js

I've got a simple [lodash](/questions/tagged/lodash) mixin:

```
var _ = require('lodash')
_.mixin(require('lodash-uuid'))
```

Which I can use in code like so:

```
if (_.isUuid(someValue)) {
   // it's a uuid!
}
```

I'd like to be able to extend [should.js](/questions/tagged/should.js)-based tests to leverage this module, for example:

```
response.should.have.property('uuid').which.is.a.uuid()
```

The [docs](https://shouldjs.github.io/#should-extend) for extending Should are a little light; I tried:

```
var uuid = should.extend('uuid', _.isUuid)
```

But that throws:

```
TypeError: response.should.have.property(...).which.is.a.uuid is not a function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used not right method. Method you used is to add should getter to any object. You need to use `should.Assertion.add`, like:

```
var should = require('should');

should.Assertion.add('uuid', function() {
  this.params = { operator: 'to be UUID' };

  this.assert(_.isUuid(this.obj));
});
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks. Should.js docs didn't leave any indication that this would be the way to do it...

Comment: Yep, probably. I will try to fix this later.